# collapsible header animation not animating

Tags: swift, uitableview

Hello I have implemented a collapsible header in my swift, the header works great, I am able to collapse and uncollapse the section. The problem is when I reload my tableView with new information the arrow in the header loses its animation and the arrow in the view does not rotate on load. If you have any ideas please let me know.

Code:

tableView -

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: CollapsableHeader.CollapsableTableHeaderIdentifier) as? CollapsableHeader {
        header.setCollapsed(false)
        header.delegate = self

        return header
    }
}
```

//after loading information I am calling

```
    self.tableView.reloadData()
```

CollapsableHeader -

// other methods

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }


    //Collapsed options
    func setCollapsed(_ collapsed: Bool) {
        //
        // Animate the arrow rotation (see Extensions.swf)
        //
        self.arrow.rotate(collapsed ? 0.0 : .pi / 2)
    }
```

Comment: header.setCollapsed(false). .Wr u r setting true ??

Comment: try checking simple code to make a collapsable TableView at https://github.com/RockinGarg/Expandable-TableView-.git

Comment: @McDonal_11 thank you for your response, I have a toggle function that is activated when user clicks on header. currently the issue occurs when loading the view and the information gets loaded

Comment: @iOSGeek thank you for your response! I followed your sample and I has missing the reload section only instead of reloading the whole table. Thank you this solved my issue!!

Comment: Accept My answer i posted Thanks , and close this thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking sample Project Made at

Link -  https://github.com/RockinGarg/Expandable-TableView-

```
//Setting Header Customised View
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        //Declare cell
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HeaderCell") as! TableViewCell

        //Setting Header Components
        headerCell.titleLabel.text = self.section[section]
        headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.tag = section

        //Handling Button Title
        if self.collapaseHandlerArray.contains(self.section[section]){
            //if its opened
            headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
        }
        else{
            //if closed
            headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
        }

        //Adding a target to button
        headerCell.ButtonToShowHide.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.HandleheaderButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return headerCell.contentView

    }
```

**Button Handler**

```
//Header cell button Action
    @objc func HandleheaderButton(sender: UIButton){

        //check status of button
        if let buttonTitle = sender.title(for: .normal) {
            if buttonTitle == "Show"{
                //if yes
                self.collapaseHandlerArray.append(self.section[sender.tag])
                sender.setTitle("Hide", for: .normal)
            }
            else {
                //if no
                while self.collapaseHandlerArray.contains(self.section[sender.tag]){
                    if let itemToRemoveIndex = self.collapaseHandlerArray.index(of: self.section[sender.tag]) {
                        //remove title of header from array
                        self.collapaseHandlerArray.remove(at: itemToRemoveIndex)
                        sender.setTitle("Show", for: .normal)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //reload section
        self.mainTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: sender.tag), with: .none)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”